# Passing a value of a variable to a different form

Tags: c#

Hi all I have 3 forms in the first form I've declared:

```
public int number1;
```

then my function sets a value to number1, and when I check the value of number1 from my console it is the value the function gives to it.

than I open my second form and with the second form I go to the 3rd form, Here I want to display the value of number1 and here is the code I use in form3:

```
private void haberlesme_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
        label1.text = frm1.number1.tostring();

    }
```

my function in form1 to set a value to number1 is:

```
public int setNumber1(string num){    
retrun convert.int32(num);
}
```

inside the button the code is:

```
number1 = setNumber1(txtValue.text);
messagebox.show("Number1 is : " + number1.toString());
// Here is the other code to open form2..
```

On a messagebox number1 is display with the assigned value from the textbox 
But when I click to open form3(haberlesme) Where in the haberlesme_load section the code is: above

It displays 0; what am I missing here?

Comment: Please provide us more code ...

Comment: Pass the arguments to the second form in it's constructor.

Comment: Your main  problem is that you are making a new instance of Form1 and expecting it to have the value  you set. maybe this link will help: http://www.contrivedexample.com/ce/post/2015/02/15/forms-are-just-classes.aspx

Comment: If you have a need for this particular variable to be shared across the 3 forms, the easiest approach is to declare it inside of a public static class.

Answer (score 2):

The default value for an `int` is `0`.  So when you create a new object:

```
Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
```

until something changes that value, it's going to be `0`.  You have a couple of options, and it's not entirely clear from the context which is the best design for you.

You could make the variable static so that there's only one in the domain, rather than one per form instance.  Something like this:

```
public static int number1;
```

Then other forms can access the value from the class rather than the instance:

```
label1.txt = Form1.number1;
```

If it genuinely should be an instance variable then you'll need a reference to the actual instance which holds the value you want.  Creating a new instance doesn't do that.

(As an analogy... Imagine that your friend has a car and he has something for you in the glove box.  If you go out and buy an identical car, that item won't be in the glove box of the new car.  It's only in the glove box of that *specific* car, not in all cars of the same type.)

That would involve passing a reference from one form to another as they're created.  For example, if `Form2` needs to reference the value then `Form2` officially has a dependency on `Form1`, so it should require it on its constructor:

```
private Form1Instance { get; set; }
public Form2(Form1 form1Instance)
{
    this.Form1Instance = form1Instance;
}
```

Then when `Form1` creates a new `Form2`, it supplies a reference to itself:

```
var form2 = new Form2(this);
form2.Show();
```

Then in `Form2` you can access that instance:

```
var theNumber = this.Form1Instance.number1;
```

If this has to continue to another form, use the same pattern.  The third form has a dependency, so it requires the reference when it's created.  Whatever form creates it therefore must supply the reference, so it also has a dependency, so it requires the reference when it's created.  And so on.

Comment: Thanks David! I Understood your point but to be crystal clear I need to ask a few more questions
1- The first technique which I use static int, my functions have to be the type of static as well right? and I don't know if it is good or not..
2- The second method I've never used but I searched from the web how to use the get&set method and I'm assuming in form3 my code should be something like this?:
private Form1 number1{ get{return this.number1;} set{this.number1=value;}
public Form3(Form1 number1){ this.number1=number1;}

and than how do I open form3? is my logic ok? or I'm  completelylost?

Comment: @user3456351: 1) A non-static method can call a static value, but not the other way around. 2) It's not clear how you're approaching the property in that code. Ultimately, any subsequent form just needs to have a variable which references back to the form you want.  It doesn't have to be a property, it can just be a member variable.  But if `Form3` needs to get a value from an instance of `Form1` then it needs a variable which holds that instance.